# Why does the multidimensional array syntax work

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

When we create a 2d array such as `int[][] a = new int[2][3]` why is the resulting 2d array consist of a two-element array that contains three-element int arrays instead of the other way around.  The reason why I'm confused is that when we make an array we do datatype[], so when we do int[2][3] why don't we put three int[2] arrays into an array with three spots (from the [3]).

Comment: To put it simply, the type of the array isn't a part of the dimensional construct. So it's not akin to thinking like `(int[2])[3]`, but rather it's a `[2][3]` array (2 by 3) with a type of `int`. In reality you can support multiple dimensions through use of modulo and multiplication yourself, and then 2x3 or 3x2 (in a 1d array) has very little distinction. As for _why_ java designed it this way, you're going to be digging through some pretty old mailing lists...

Answer (score 1):

The way it's implemented in Java is more logical. Consider the array element access expression: `a[x][y]`. Currently, it could be nicely decomposed to `(a[x])[y]` which means "we get an x-th element of `a`, then we get a y-th element of the result". So imagine if `new int[2][3]` produced an array of three elements, each is a two-element array. Then the `x` should be in range 0..2 and `y` should be in range 0..1 which is the opposite of the dimension order used at the array creation point. That would be absolutely confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a point with your logic. Eventhough you could also argument, writing `int[2][3]` means "first index can have 2 different values, second 3", what leads to the same as how it really works.

In the end, this is just a matter of specification and compilerbuilding. And since it is specified this way and not that way, it is implemented and works this way.